# Returning values from an array in reactjs without using this.state

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 arrays of elements(Users, Comments, Ratings) and I need for 2 of them to output the coresponding value from the first. Something like:

```
functionComments(users_id)
{
returns the coresponding comments after iterating through}

functionRatings(users_id){returns the coresponding ratings after iterating}

{this.state.Users.map(u=>{

{<Card >{functionComments(u.id)<Card/>}
{<Card >{functionRatings(u.id)<Card/>}
})}
```

But I have no idea how to return the value without using this.state

elements in a User array look like this

```
Users: {
                "firstName": "diana",
                "lastName": "diana",
                "age": "0",
                "email": "mari@yahoo.com",
                "password": "123456",
                "name": "diana",
                "username": "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
                "description": "12346",
                "address": null,
                  "id":45
    }
    
    Comments:
    
       {
                "username": "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
                "commentsList": [
                    {
                        "comment": "loc",
                        "id": 40,
                        "username": "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
                        "movieID": "tt6048922"
                    }
                ]
            }
    
    Ratings
    
    {
                "username": "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
                "ratingsList": [
                    {
                        "rating": 5,
                        "id": 50,
                        "username": "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
                        "movieID": "tt3089630"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

The output JSON I want to get:

```
  {
    username: usernameleters,
    firstName: userFirstName,
    commentsList:[
       {
            comments:"comm"
            movieID:"movie"
       }],
    ratingsList:[
        {
          rating:"rrt"
          movieID:"mm"
        }] 

}
```

The fetches for the 3 arrays look like this :

```
async  reloadObjectiveList() {
        await  UserApiService.fetchUsers()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    Users: res.data.result
                })
            });

     await   CommentApiService.fetchComments()
            .then((res) => {
                console.log( res.data.result)
                this.setState({

                    Comments:  res.data.result
                })
            });    console.log(this.state.Comments)
     await   RatingApiService.fetchrating()
            .then((res) => {
                console.log( res.data.result)
                this.setState({

                    Ratings:  res.data.result
                })
            });
     }
   componentDidMount()
    {
        this.reloadObjectiveList();
        const userData = (this.mergeData(this.state.Users, this.state.Comments, this.state.Ratings));
        console.log("user data "+ this.userData)
        this.setState({UserData:this.userData})


    }
```

Comment: why do you insist in not using this.state ?

Comment: Why not "preprocess" the three arrays into a ***single*** data array? This seems l like a lot of extra repeated work to do ***every*** render cycle.

Comment: Because it's not a fixed ammount of data from comments/ratings, one user might have 3 comments and ratings, another might have 3 ratings 0 comments, and I want to iterate through all the Users list and print them allong wit the coresponding commennts

Comment: That would work if I could figure out how to mix them. A user with no comments or ratings still needs to be printed.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of the three arrays? It's a trivial matter to convert an array to an object/Map to provide `O(1)` constant time lookups, or to merge them, but it's impossible to provide help for this if we've no idea what the data looks like or what your expected result should be.

Comment: So for the user array you are mapping, you are using `username` as the key into the other arrays, are you further mapping the `commentsList` and `ratingsList` properties?

Comment: I need from the commentsList the Comment and MovieID and from rating the Rating and MovieID, it would be nice if I could print the movie  name, but I really just want to have this part done. I can't find an example for this  mapping

Comment: could you add your result in JSON format?  what do you like the final output to be?

Comment: ```{
username: usernameleters,
firstName: userFirstName,
commentsList:[
    {
        comments:"$schema"
        movieID:"movie"
    }
],
ratingsList:[{
    rating:"rrt"
    movieID:"mm"
}]

}``` something like this, and the 2 fields commentList and ratingList to be empty when there is no output but the user HAS to be printed.

Comment: The way you format your code makes me dizzy.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way around using local component state to help improve the efficiency of your component. Using a utility function to merge all the data into an initial state object, you can run this once and won't have to recompute it again and again, for each render cycle. This especially avoids the nested `O(n)` search-looping through each array to find the corresponding array element matching `username`, making the runtime of the render function really `O(n^2)`(*!!*) since you're already looping over the user array once per render cycle.

You can create a utility function that takes the three arrays and gracefully merges comments and ratings lists into the user array.

```
const mergeData = (users, comments, ratings) => {
  const mapData = (arr, userKey, propertyKey) => arr.reduce((map, curr) => {
    map[curr[userKey]] = (curr[propertyKey] || []).map(el => {
      const elCopy = {...el}
      delete elCopy[userKey]; // remove duplicated key from child array elements
      return elCopy;
    });
    return map;
  }, {});

  // Generate map objects
  const commentsMap = mapData(comments, 'username', 'commentsList');
  const ratingsMap = mapData(ratings, 'username', 'ratingsList');

  return users.map(user => ({
    ...user,
    // Grab comments and ratings lists from maps using current username
    commentsList: commentsMap[user.username],
    ratingsList: ratingsMap[user.username],
  }));
};
```

```js
const users = [
  {
    firstName: "diana",
    lastName: "diana",
    age: "0",
    email: "mari@yahoo.com",
    password: "123456",
    name: "diana",
    username: "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
    description: "12346",
    address: null,
    id: 45
  }
];

const comments = [
  {
    username: "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
    commentsList: [
      {
        comment: "loc",
        id: 40,
        username: "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
        movieID: "tt6048922"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const ratings = [
  {
    username: "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
    ratingsList: [
      {
        rating: 5,
        id: 50,
        username: "Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2",
        movieID: "tt3089630"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const mergeData = (users, comments, ratings) => {
  const mapData = (arr, userKey, propertyKey) => arr.reduce((map, curr) => {
    map[curr[userKey]] = (curr[propertyKey] || []).map(el => {
      const elCopy = {...el}
      delete elCopy[userKey];
      return elCopy;
    });
    return map;
  }, {});

  const commentsMap = mapData(comments, 'username', 'commentsList');
  const ratingsMap = mapData(ratings, 'username', 'ratingsList');

  return users.map(user => ({
    ...user,
    commentsList: commentsMap[user.username],
    ratingsList: ratingsMap[user.username],
  }));
};

console.log(mergeData(users, comments, ratings));
```

When the component mounts you can pass these three arrays to `mergeData` and set initial state (i.e. in `componentDidMount` or a state initializer in `useState` hook in functional components).

```
function App() {
  const [userData] = useState(mergeData(users, comments, ratings));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      {userData.map(({ name, username, commentsList, ratingsList }) => (
        <div key={username}>
          <div>User: {name}</div>
          <Card>
            Comments:{" "}
            {commentsList.map(({ movieID, comment }) => (
              <div key={movieID}>
                Movie: {movieID}, Comment: {comment}
              </div>
            ))}
          </Card>
          <Card>
            Ratings:{" "}
            {ratingsList.map(({ movieID, rating }) => (
              <div key={movieID}>
                Movie: {movieID}, Rating: {rating}
              </div>
            ))}
          </Card>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Merge 3 arrays for initial state object]

## Edit

For fetch utility and `componentDidMount`

You are mixing up async/await with promise chains. You need only await the resolved fetch responses, and you can pass the response data to the `mergeData` utility, then update state. `componentDidMount` can simply call `reloadObjectiveList`.

By using a promise chain and updating state intermittently you are queuing up state updates that are only accessible in later render cycles, `componentDidMount` has already exited by then.

```
async function reloadObjectiveList() {
  try {
    const usersRes = await UserApiService.fetchUsers();
    const commentsRes = await CommentApiService.fetchComments();
    const ratingsRes = await RatingApiService.fetchrating();

    const userData = this.mergeData(
      usersRes.data.result,
      commentsRes.data.result,
      ratingsRes.data.result,
    );

    this.setState({ userData });
  } catch {
    // Error, maybe set some error state for the UI?
  }

}

function componentDidMount() {
  this.reloadObjectiveList();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it wait for the components to load? for example, Users, Comments, Ratings are results from API calls to backend for data, it takes a while for them to load and the function fires too fast

Comment: @Miss Yes, absolutely there is. Assuming these are three individual fetches, you can create an async function to make and await the responses, or load up all three fetches into `Promise.all`, and when you have the three arrays run them through this utility and update local component state.

Comment: @Miss If you don't mind, can you update your question with the three fetches and your `componentDidMount` function? It's really difficult to read formatted code in a comment that is more than a single line expression.

Comment: Somehow, it waits for the users but not for the comments or ratings, I have updates the post

Comment: @Miss Updated answer to include `reloadObjectiveList` utility usage and likely reason it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can follow this simple approach

I'm Assuming your inputs looks like this

```
const users = [
  {
    firstName: 'diana',
    lastName: 'diana',
    age: '0',
    email: 'mari@yahoo.com',
    password: '123456',
    name: 'diana',
    username: 'Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2',
    description: '12346',
    address: null,
    id: 45,
  },
];

const Comments = [
  {
    username: 'Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2',
    commentsList: [
      {
        comment: 'loc',
        id: 40,
        username: 'Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2',
        movieID: 'tt6048922',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const Ratings = [
  {
    username: 'Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2',
    ratingsList: [
      {
        rating: 5,
        id: 50,
        username: 'Rn9h8fJfs1XvTv1Y9Sr1mXWB7ib2',
        movieID: 'tt3089630',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

this will generate the response as you expected

```
const getUserdata = () => {
  const finalUsersData = users.map(user => {
    const userOutput = {
      username: user.username,
      firstName: user.firstName,
    };
    const userComments = Comments.find(comment => comment.username === user.username);
    userOutput.commentsList = userComments ? userComments.commentsList : [];

    const userRatings = Ratings.find(rating => rating.username === user.username);
    userOutput.userRatings = userRatings ? userRatings.ratingsList : [];

    return userOutput;
  });

  return finalUsersData;
};
```

Output will be like this

```
  {
    username: usernameleters,
    firstName: userFirstName,
    commentsList:[
       {
            comments:"comm"
            movieID:"movie"
       }],
    ratingsList:[
        {
          rating:"rrt"
          movieID:"mm"
        }] 

}
```

please update the references as necessary. If you are storing `users` , `comments` and `ratings` in state make sure you refrence then using `this.state.users` and so on.